# Android java insert to sql-server datatype (conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier)

Tags: java, android, sql-server

I'm having problem with the uniqueidentifier from MySQL which is when i tried to insert an array of data into a table that has a uniqueidentifier datatype in one of the column, it just says conversion failed when converting string to uniqueidentifier.

Here's MySQL block:

```
    if (Gender.trim().equals(""))
                z = "Value not enough";
            else {
                try {
                    Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                    if (con == null) {
                        z = "Error in connection with SQL server";
                    } else {


                        final String query = "USE [dbtest]" +
                                "insert into [tablename] ([DepositorID],[Name],[Sex],[DateOfBirth],[Race],[Occupation],[Occupation_others],[AddressLine1],[AddressLine2],[Postcode]," +
                                "[City],[State],[AgeSah],[TelNo],[HPNo],[Email],[Bank],[BankNo],[CreatedBy],[CreatedOn],[ModifiedBy],[ModifiedOn]) values " +
                                "('" + nokppv + "','" + Namev + "','" + sex + "','" + Date + "','" + Race + "','" + Occupation + "','" + Occupation2 + "','" + Address + "','" + Address2 +
                                "','" + Postcode + "','" + City + "','" + State +  "','" + agesah +  "','" + telno +  "','" + Phonev  + "','"+ Email  +"','"+ Bank  +"','"+ BankNo +
                                "',' "+ chars +"','"+ CreatedOn +"','"+ chars1  +"','" + ModifiedOn + "')";
                        System.out.println("Query:"+query);
                        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

                        if (rs.next()){
                            z = "Registration successful";
                            isSuccess = true;
                        }else {
                            z = "Registration error";
                            isSuccess = false;
                        }


                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    isSuccess = false;
                    z = "Exceptions";
                    System.err.println("Message:"+ex.getMessage());
                    System.err.println("Cause:"+ex.getCause());
                    System.out.println("Query:"+query);
                }
            }


    }

        return z;
    }
```

The things that I already tried

1. The column for uniqueidentifier allows null and tried to insert it null, same error.
2. Tried android GUID code, same error, found out sql server uid are sequential which is different from java uid.
3. Tried declaring UniqueIdentifier variable from JDBC library, same error.

I did found some post that mention of UID generator thats generate a sequential UID that compatible to SQL UID datatype but the post answer was very vague.
I just need hints or a few example to make my own code I hope I provide enough data. Anyone willing to show me the rope around? BTW I'm using MSSQL 2016
and using Android Studio as Java platform.

Comment: You should use `CONVERT` or `NEWID`

Comment: Is `DepositorID` a `uniqueidentifie` and you try to pass `nokppv` which contain `string`?

Comment: I'll give it a shot with CONVERT, but isn't NEWID are from C#?  theres NEWID in java as well?

Comment: every variable except CreatedBy and ModifiedBy are String, just these two are UniqueIdentifier

Comment: BTW its the variable chars and chars1, tried convert string to char, to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
+"CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,'"+chars+"' )"

+"CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,'"+chars1+"' )"
```

You should get :

```
values ('840403055141','Shariffah Saralisha binti Syed Ali','P','04-03-1984','K','015','null','No 43, Jalan valera 1/3, Taman Tingtong','null','43900','Sepang','K','Y','null','0123456789‌​','Demo@emailhost.co‌​m','123','123',CONV‌​ERT(uniqueidentifier‌​,'55555555-2222-2222‌​-2222-222222222222')‌​,'2017-02-16 19:59:22','CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,'22222222-2222-2222-2222‌​-222222222222'),'nul‌​l')
```

Comment: the error went away thanks alot but this error pops up next

Comment: values ('840403055141','Shariffah Saralisha binti Syed Ali','P','04-03-1984','K','015','null','No 43, Jalan valera 1/3, Taman Tingtong','null','43900','Sepang','K','Y','null','0123456789','Demo@emailhost.com','123','123','CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,'55555555-2222-2222-2222-222222222222'),'2017-02-16 19:59:22','CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,'22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222'),'null')

Comment: the error was Incorrect syntax near '5555555' . i checked the query but there were nothing visibly wrong with it. i know its the first uniqueid, which is CreatedBy, but the two column before it allows null

Comment: I try to convert it and it's fine , @ReanyMeany check my update.

Comment: i tried to run the insert directly in mssql but the error came out that conversion from string to uniqueidentifier failed. is there maybe any setting that i need to flip the switch for it to work? and the one you updated, no Apostrophe for that one?

Comment: Did you try `SELECT CONVERT (uniqueidentifier , '55555555-2222-2222-2222-222222222222')AS UI;` ?

Comment: i did as follow with the convert in my query string the ui failed conversion error went away but new error with conversion failed when converting date and or time from character string, do i convert my datetime and date column the same way with the ui column?

Comment: Solved all the problems now :D , thanks for helping out! @Sami